# How to perform Opayo Integration using PHP

Tags: encryption, integration, opayo

I'm trying to add integration with Opayo payment on website.

The form

I just have this code:
I change card and card holder details for security reason

```
$text ='Description=Finishing transaction&Currency=GBP&VendorTxCode=22013115512924219800&amount=5.00&BillingSurname=Paul&BillingFirstnames=Smith&BillingAddress1=ddd&BillingCity=London&BillingPostCode=BH99PU&BillingCountry=GB&DeliveryState=&DeliverySurname=Jhon&DeliveryFirstnames=Jhon&DeliveryAddress1=ddd&DeliveryCity=London&DeliveryPostCode=BH99PU&BillingState=&DeliveryCountry=GB&VendorData=Testing Data &ApplyAVSCV2=2&referid=&language=&website=&Phone=SendEmail=&CardHolder=Smith Alves Gomety&Cardnumber=5434391244446116&ExpiryDate=1229&CardType=MC';

$key = "yuG4B75PE2Gaqgus";
$iv = hex2bin('00000000000000000000000000000000');
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($text , "AES-128-CBC", $key , OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hex = bin2hex($ciphertext_raw);
$hex ='@' . $hex;
<form method="POST" id="SagePayForm" action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value= "4.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value= "PAYMENT">
    <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value= "<?php echo $hex; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="continue to SagePay">
</form>
```

The page comes like following

[Page generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGMuG.png)

And, when I click on "Continue to SagePay" I'm receiving the following

[Ssubmiting result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd2wZ.png)

Does anyone can help me with this?

How to integrate in my own form or on SagePay?

Does anyone has full PHP code to this integration including returnings codes,,,,

Comment: Which of their APIs are you actually using?

Comment: https://developer-eu.elavon.com/node/4666

Comment: You are missing some mandatory fields (Failure URL etc) and you have some fields you shouldn't provide (Credit card information) https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-forms/opayo-form-integration-overview/2-your-server-builds-confirmation-page/html-form-fields/crypt-field

Comment: "Use the provided password as both the key and initialisation vector and encode the result in hex" try `$iv = $key;`.